# Combine multiple tables in Excel for Mac

Tags: excel

I’ve searched for related questions but non seem to have the same use case I’m trying to solve for. Please forgive the duplication if any.

After many hours of Googling and watching YouTube I know this can be done but I can’t get it to work. Any advice would be great.

Please note. I'm using Excel for Mac.

---

### What is my data?

I've got several named tables across many sheets that relate to design tokens. All tables are two columns with the same table header row.

#### Example data

##### Global font tokens:

*Table name: tokens_global_font*

| Token | Default value |
| --- | --- |
| $cds-global-font-stack | 'Roboto', Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif; |
| $cds-global-font-stack-decorative | 'Roboto', Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif; |
| $cds-global-font-size | 16px |

#### Global Colour tokens:

*Table name: tokens_global_colour*

| Token | Default value |
| --- | --- |
| $cds-global-color-chameleon_green-50 | hsl(184, 32%, 93%) |
| $cds-global-color-chameleon_green-100 | hsl(184, 32%, 86%) |
| $cds-global-color-chameleon_green-150 | hsl(184, 32%, 78%) |

### What am I'm trying to do?

I need to create a master table that will consolidate all tables into one. This table needs to be dynamic so if data is added to any of the source tables it’s also added to the master. If any values change, then they are propagated.

### What have I tried?

The consolidate feature which doesn’t seem to do anything. I get “Alert no data was consolidated” after I add my tables.

I’ve also tried using Power Query. But what this does is create additional sheets with the same data in separate tables.

---

With both of these methods I’m probably doing something wrong but this is the most advanced thing I’ve ever tried to do in Excel so consider me a novice.

Comment: Do the tables have a common element like id number? if so, index() with match() may work. However, post example data that can be copied for testing.

Comment: Do you mean common element in the name of the table or the data within the table? The names are all prefixed with "tokens_". The data within the table is unique in each table. I'll update with the question with examples, thanks.

Comment: @Nick What is you excel version for Mac? If it Microsoft365 and you have access to office insiders or beta channel or current preview channel then you use `VSTACK()` formula.

Comment: @Harun24hr I'm using the desktop version 16.64 with an Office 365 subscription. I just looked up VSTACK() and it's exactly what I need but doesn't work in my current version. I get the #NAME? error.

Comment: @Nick Then you have to enable current preview to you desktop apps (For Microsoft Office). Check this link. You will get link for Mac here to left pane https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/office-insider/deploy/office-deployment-tool?fbclid=IwAR3NJMea6wzxPyWZvqoxIeyxbJs8u4KhcmhiPZoLm2E6l_IM7q1yzQYLz1g

Comment: @Nick If you wish I can post this as an answer so that you can accept it.

Comment: @Harun24hr I haven't logged into Stack Overflow since seeing your last comment so apologies for not responding. Bad form on my part. Your solution was exactly what I was looking for so if you still want to post that as an answer I'll mark it as accepted - I appreciate it's been over a year though.

Comment: @Nick Glad to know! I have added as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you want to stack data from multiple table to one master sheet, then `VSTACK()` would be best choice. Give a try-

```
=VSTACK(Table1,Table2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the Filterxml function.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ibcbh8ep3Is

```
H2  =SUM(ROWS(MyTable1);ROWS(MyTable2))
H3  =MAX(COLUMNS(MyTable1);COLUMNS(MyTable2))
G7  =SEQUENCE($H$2;$H$3;1)
J7  ="<m><r>"&TEXTJOIN("</r><r>";FALSE;A2:B4;D2:E4)&"</r></m>"
J9  =FILTERXML("<m><r>"&TEXTJOIN("</r><r>";FALSE;A2:B4;D2:E4)&"</r></m>";"//r")
J24 =INDEX(FILTERXML("<m><r>"&TEXTJOIN("</r><r>";FALSE;A2:B4;D2:E4)&"</r></m>";"//r");SEQUENCE($H$2;$H$3;1))
```

[image]

Comment: This is an interesting one. I'll check this out. Thank you.